# Using table variable for iteration?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

What I've got is an attempt to build a stored procedure to be run as a Sql Server Agent Job at a regular interval of a minute.  It will look at `Table X` which has a bunch of stuff, and in particular I'm interested in the `sent_time` column.  Currently, the stored procedure seeks out the most recent record from within between 15 and 16 minutes and does everything it needs to just fine.  My problem is of course that there can exist more than one record within that timespan.    So the idea I have is to throw all results (not just the most recent) from that timespan into my table variable `declare @alertId table (alerts int)`.  Then I want to use whatever `Ids` that get thrown into that table variable in the rest of the stored procedures to send out messages based on the `Ids` that are stored.  Hence the idea of **Iterating based on a table variable**.  More to the point however, is that I need access to each and every individual `Id` that is stored there as it will need to be passed as a parameter for other processing.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  I realize there is a lack of code here but I'm not having any issue pertaining to the code I currently have, its more so that I don't know how to progress from here and haven't had any luck trying to find any information to help me begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to iterate through a table is to use a cursor. Here's another way which I like better for purely esthetic reasons. Performance-wise there's not going to be much difference.

```
declare @alertId table (ID int primary key clustered, alerts int);

-- throw some Ids into @alertId here

declare @id int = -1; -- make sure this is less than any valid alert ID

while 1=1  
begin
    select top(1) @id = ID 
    from @alertId 
    where ID > @id 
    order by ID asc;

    if @id is null break; -- we're done

    -- do whatever needs to be done with @id
    print @id
end
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a go this afternoon and see how it works out for me so thank you.  Of course if this is the solution I use I will select it

Comment: I did end up doing a `while` loop using a structure where I set the loop flag equal to the number of IDs that were pulled and it works just fine so thanks!